# Which "except" has priority in nested "try" statements?

Tags: python, exception

I have a very delicate part in my code that I am trying to optimize and I need error handling to be perfect. Here is a simplification of my function:

```
try:
    try:
        # Do something
        # Serial communication
    except Exception as e: 
        # Do something
        break
except Big_error:
    # Do something
    break
```

I know this might seem trivial, but which `except` has priority? My `Big_error` can be caught by the `Exception` but I want it to be caught on the last except.

(Is this even good practice?)

Comment: The innermost matching `except` has priority. If you want to pass the exception to the next higher `except` just call `raise` without arguments inside the inner `except` block.

Comment: Thanks! so `except Big_error:` will never happen? and won't `raise` raise every possible error caught?

Comment: Only if it is reraised from `except Exception`. And, if `Big_error` is a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: `Big_error` can happen if it is raises inside  the `except Exception as e:` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if `#serial communication` throws a `Big_error`, only the first `except Exception as e` will catch the error. If a `Big_errror` is thrown from inside the `catch` block, (assuming `not issubclass(Big_error, KeyError)`) then the second exception will be thrown. You can abuse this behavior to rewrite your code like this:

```
try:
    try:
        # Serial Communication
    except BigError:
        raise
    except Exception:
        try:
            # Error handling
        except KeyError:
            # KeyError handling
except BigError:
    # BigError handling
```

Here, the `raise` statement will make sure the exception never reaches the generic except.

Comment: So the `raise` will skip the `except Exception`?

Comment: Yes, every exception handler applies only to the `try` statement, not to any other exception handlers. Note that the same principle does *not* apply to `finally`

Answer (score 0):

The `except` handlers in your code are not in a sequence or anything, so "priority" doesn't apply.

The block with `except Exception` looks just like a `# do something` to the outer block. Either it raises, or it doesn't. And, as it stands, `except Exception` will intercept `Big_error` and swallow it, unless you re-raise.

Answer (score 0):

If `Big_error` occurs in the `# Serial communication` block, is catched by the `except Exception as e` because is the base class (it's not a good practice to catch `Exception` always try to specify which exception is going to happen)

If you want it to be catched in the last except do this:

```
try:
    # Do something
    # Serial communication
except Big_error:
    # Big_error handling
except KeyError:
    # KeyError handling
except Exception:  # try to avoid this one
    # rest of errors
```